# Why does fopen fail the first time, but work the second time?

Tags: matlab, file-io, ubuntu, fopen

I am using Matlab to create a new file by calling

```
fid = fopen(filename,'w')
```

since filename doesn't exist, it should create a new file and give me a valid file descriptor.  Instead it returns -1. If I run the code again however, I get fid = 3.

This is being run on ubuntu but it apparently works fine on windows and I can't figure out why.

-Mike

Comment: Have you tried getting the message of the error to see what it tells you? You can do so by adding another output argument to the call: `[fid,message] = fopen(filename,'w')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if this helps, but note that if the folder doesn't exist, fopen with 'w' can't create the file and so returns -1.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the two-output-argument form of `fopen` in the doc [here](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fopen.html). This allows you to do stuff like

```
[fh, failmessage] = fopen( fname, 'wt' );
if fh == -1
    error( 'Failed to open %s: %s', fname, failmessage );
end
```